# Store immediate value to memory on ARM, with register + displacement addressing

Tags: assembly, x86, arm

I'm working on some assembly for ARM architectures and am trying to figure out if it is possible to move an immediate value into a shifted register(register + offset).

This is an example of what I'm trying to do on a x86 architecture:

```
movl $0x43e00000, 0x4(%0)
```

`%0` is any register. I basically am trying to repeat the above code but on an ARM architecture. From the documentation I've read, I can't seem to find a way to accomplish this.

Comment: the arm documentation covers the instruction set, did you look it up?

Comment: @dwelch I've looked at the ARM instruction set but the closest I could find to what I'm looking for is moving a immediate value into a unshifted register. Is there a particular instruction I should be looking at that allows moving into shifted register?

Comment: What do you mean by "shifted register"? That has a specific meaning in ARM terminology which is not what we seem to be dealing with here. That x86 instruction is writing an immediate direct to memory (`mov dword ptr [%0 + 4], 0x43e00000` in sensible form) - ARM can't do that, since it's a load-store architecture. You need to first put the immediate into a register, than store that register to the memory address.

Comment: @Notlikethat So it would be 2 steps then: `mov x1, #0x43e00000` and `str [%0, 0x4], x1`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Notlikethat Or I guess the syntax would be `str x1, [%0, 0x4]` for the second step?

Comment: That is correct.  It is a price for not being able to fry eggs on your CPU [or more technically, it will reduce the transistor count].  It is common to RISC CPUs, not just the ARM.